# designing model structure for django

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I'm trying to design a model for a application allowing 2 people to bet with each other (I know, sounds stupid...). What I'm wondering about is how to connect the bet with users. The structure is like this

```
|-------------|       |----------|
|    Bet      |       | User     |
| BetUser1    |       |----------|
| BetUser2    |
| Winner      |
| ...         |
|-------------|
```

So we got 2 people that bet with each other (both are `Users` from django auth system) and then, after one of them wins, there's a winner. Now all those 3 fields are of type `User`, but:

- Should I make BetUser1 and BetUser2 separate fields, or design some many-to-two relationship here? (with many-to-two being a many-to-many and with some external way of ensuring no more then 2 `Users` can be assigned to each bet?
- winner can only be either user 1 or user 2, noone else of course. How should I create this field, yet another `ForeignKey(User)`, or some else?

Just looking for some fresh point of view, as it seems that in such stupid case I'm stuck with the django model system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably add a third model to represent a specific wager someone has placed, as it is conceivable that more than two people could enter into a bet.  It would look something like this:

```
USER        WAGER              BET
             User (FK(User))    Description
             Bet  (FK(Bet))     Winner (FK (Wager), null=True)
             Amount
```

Django will automatically generate `user.wager_set` and `bet.wager_set` based on the foreign keys.  This allows you to easily iterate and display the wagers for a bet, as well as the wagers from each user.  You can also add a `unique_together` constraint on `User` and `Bet` in the Wager table so that each user can only make one wager.

When the betting is all done, and a winner has been selected, you just set `bet.winner`.

In case you run into it, you might see a warning about `related_name` by having `Bet` point to `Wager` and `Wager` point to `Bet`.  To fix, just add `related_name=wagers` to `Wager.bet`.

Comment: This needs a constraint to limit it to two Wager instances for the same Bet.  I'd suggest adding a method to check this, and raising an exception if someone attempts to save a third Wager for a given Bet.

Comment: @S.Lott how would I actually code that? I need to make own Wager.save() method that checks it before calling Model.save(self)?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Many-to-Many relation with extra data (e.g. the amount on the wager, the time entered,...)

There is a [chaper](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on this in the excellent Django docs on writing models.

Tyler has already outlined the proper schema for this.